# How do you get the map in the upper right corner?

Tags: might-and-magic-2-another-world

In [Might and Magic II: Gates to Another World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Might_and_Magic_II:_Gates_to_Another_World) (SNES version, if it matters), how do you activate the map in the top right corner?

I have a character with the cartography ability, but still got no map there.

In the Wikipedia [it says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Might_and_Magic_II:_Gates_to_Another_World#Gameplay):

> The game introduced an automap feature to the series, activated by training a character in the cartographer skill.

I guess this refers to <kbd>Menu → "Auto-Map"</kbd>. This opens a full-screen map. (Do you get *this* map only if you know cartography?!)

[At minute 4:00](http://youtu.be/j6tLKDySets?t=4m) you can see that the "radar" map gets activated when the player drinks from the fountain in Middlegate (**Drink from the fountain of Clairvoyance?**). However, this effect lasts only until your party rests.

In which other ways can this map be enabled? Is there a spell? An ability? An item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're are looking for the spell "Wizard Eye" (Sorcerer level 3).  I don't remember if M&M2 used the same system as M&M1...in case it does, it's spell 3-6.